# convert string ("2022-12-23T07:20:00" ) time into ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, string, java-time, zoneddatetime

i was trying to convet string time into ZonedDateTime but not comes up with solution . This is the string format of time "2022-12-23T07:20:00"

i have tried this approach

String stringDate = "2022-12-23T07:20:00";

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
ZonedDateTime ztdOfDateOfPurchase = ZonedDateTime.parse(stringDate , dateTimeFormatter);

 this error is coming=> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-12-23T07:20:00' could not be parsed at index 19
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply parse your date-time string using [`LocalDateTime#parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) and add the applicable `ZoneId` to get the `ZonedDateTime`.

Note that `java.time` API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) and therefore you do not need a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse a date-time string which is already in ISO 8601 format (e.g. your date-time string, `2022-12-23T07:20:00`).

**Demo**:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2022-12-23T07:20:00");

        // Replace ZoneId.systemDefault() with the applicable zone ID e.g.
        // ZoneId.of("America/New_York")
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println(zdt);

        // Alternatively,
        zdt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println(zdt);
    }
}
```

**Output in my timezone**:

```
2022-12-23T07:20Z[Europe/London]
2022-12-23T07:20Z[Europe/London]
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.